# How to use WebView flutter to restrict Navigation to some pages

Tags: flutter, dart

I',m trying to use webview in my flutter app to take me back to the app once they navigate to a restricted url

I already created the controller and set it in my init state

```
  
    super.initState();
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            SmartDialog.showLoading();
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {},
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            SmartDialog.dismiss();
          },
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
            SmartDialog.showToast('Something went wrong');
            Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                context, '/landingpage', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            } else if (request.url.endsWith('page5')) {
              Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  context, '/landingpage', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
            } else if (request.url.startsWith(
                'https://www.facebook.com/')) {
              Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          verifyquickbuy(price: int.parse(widget.price))),
                  (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
            }

            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://google.com'));
  }
```

I tried putting a print in the onNavigationRequest to know if it print all url I visit but it only works just when the webview is activated

```
    getcontroller();
    return SafeArea(
        child: WebViewWidget(
      controller: controller,
      //gestureRecognizers: GestureDetector,
    ));
  }
}
```